# Casting from a list of lists of strings to list of lists of ints in Python

Tags: python

I'm reading some numbers from a data source that represent x- and y-coordinates that I'll be using for a [TSP-esque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem.  I'm new to Python, so I'm trying to make the most of lists.  After reading and parsing through the data, I'm left with a list of string lists that looks like this:

> [['565.0', '575.0'], ['1215.0',
> '245.0'], ...yougetthepoint...
> ['1740.0', '245.0']]

I would rather be dealing with integer points.  How can I transform these lists containing strings to lists containing ints?  They don't seem to be casting nicely, as I get this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int()
> with base 10: '565.0'

The decimal seems to be causing issues.

Comment: Please don't call this "casting".  Python doesn't use "casting".  Your question isn't about "casting" as it appears in Java or C++, either.  Your question is about simple conversion of data from string to float.

Comment: @S. Lott how is the "simple conversion of data from string to float" not casting?  Terminology aside, it's doing the same thing..

Comment: S. Lott is correct.  You are creating a float object from a string object.  "Casting" in statically-typed languages do not create a new object, they just reinterpret the same object with a different type and if the original object is deleted, so is the cast.  In Python, if I define a string s="123.4", then float(s) creates a new object entirely, independent of the original string.  This is why what you do in Python is not the same thing as a cast.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
x = [['565.0', '575.0'], ['1215.0', '245.0'], ['1740.0', '245.0']]
x = [[int(float(j)) for j in i] for i in x]
```

Comment: What broken generator produced just a period?

Comment: None of them are just periods.  That's what's curious.  It's running from inside of textmate.

Comment: Perhaps you are running this on a list of strings rather than a list of lists of strings, or perhaps one of the list's element is a string and the rest are lists? In that case it will try to convert each character separately, which would bring up a period as an element.

Comment: Works fine from interactive mode.  Que slique!

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on but I just tested this in a separate case and this is the answer.  Thanks Max S

Comment: Amazing! Thank you